# How to get substring from URL string according to my following example?

Tags: ios, swift, string, substring

I want to get file name from the URL string. I how to get the exact file name from the string.

Example1: http://someserver/media/health_tools_media/bbt/3Xh5No5b6P/IMG-0023-01.PNG

I want IMG-0023-01.PNG this sub-string.

Example2: http://someserver/media/health_tools_media/bbt/YnDOLNLu2V/Nature-Background09.JPG

I want Nature-Background09.JPG this sub-string.

Comment: And this is why absolutely avoid using Strings for modelling URLs, when possible. Because there's a fully fleshed out URL API, which does common stuff like this. No more messing around with regexes, manual `/` appending, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create url from string and use `lastPathComponent` will give you name of your file.

```
if let url = URL(string: "http://someserver/media/health_tools_media/bbt/3Xh5No5b6P/IMG-0023-01.PNG") {
    print(url.lastPathComponent)
}
```

Comment: It's working for me.

Comment: Pleasure to help you. But there are lots of same questions on SO, so when next time please find it and you can't then post question.